# sstable2json in cassandra 3.5,

Tags: cassandra

In 2.x versions of cassandra we can view sstable content with `bin/sstable2json sstable.db` What is proper way of checking sstable data in new version.3.x(currently 3.5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out `sstabledump`. It has replaced `sstable2json` in Cassandra 3.X.

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/debugging-sstables-in-3-0-with-sstabledump